# Strange misbehavior of 'find'

Tags: macos, zsh, find

```
WGroleau@MBP-WWG Music % Music find * -type d -name "*Andy*" -print
……/Patsy Cline/The Definitive Collection/13 Imagine That.mp3
```

I've used this method of locating a directory many times, and have never seen it do this till today.

All directories from here down have permissions `drwxrwxr-x`.

Why would the above command print the name of a file instead of a directory, and why would it print one that does not contain the search string?  (The ellipses are just to shorten a very long path; they do not hide the search string.). And why would it fail to list the directories I was looking for, which **do** exist?

I tagged the OS and shell, but I doubt that it is platform-specific.  If it matters, locale is utf8.

Comment: Does anything change if you use `find ./*` instead? Do you have any file name starting with a dash?

Comment: No, and no.  Like I said, I have done this many times.  Perhaps I should also have said several of those times $pwd = this same directory.  Some of the matches to * contain hyphens but none of them start with it.

Comment: Pipe the command to `xxd` or similar tool. Search for unusual characters: e.g. carriage return or ANSI escape sequences. If `find` prints multiple matches and this single one is weird then maybe there are newlines in some matching path and you're concerned about a *fragment*. Try `find ./* -type d -name "*Andy*" -exec ls -ld {} +`. Does it find the same suspicious file?

Comment: But it doesn’t find multiple.  It only finds one, and that one does not contain the all-ASCII search string.

Comment: So what is the output of `find * -type d -name "*Andy*" -print | xxd`? How about `find * -type d -name "*Andy*" -exec ls -ld {} +`? And to lose dependency from the shell, invoke `find . -type d -name "*Andy*" -print`. Does it also find the same unexpected file?